# How to select an element from a "ul >li :nth-child(1) " in selenium through cssSelector

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to select an WebElement from a list on a page that is present on https://www.prana.com/men/tops/shirts.html

I want to be able to select the nth child from the list, so no matter what Items change it will always select the 1st or 2nd or 3rd or whatever I set it to.

at the moment I have :

```
// This sets Child = to the first child in the list and then click the anchor  point  
      WebElement Child =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul > li:nth- 
       child(1)"));
      //move the mouse to Child ( the first image)
      action.moveToElement(Child).perform();
      // then click on the first Image
      action.click(Child);
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul > li:nth-child(1)")).click();
```

The action.click and the final line I have been trying one or the other with no success. Eclipse does not throw an error it actually passes when I have action.click(child); but it throws a object is not intractable error when I have the final line in there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of ul tags that are followed by li
if you specify which list to be iterated nth-child will work
for example:

```
#c-drop > li:nth-child(1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, yes stating the list selected it perfectly!!